# Syncopated piano sustain pedal playback on Finale

Tags: finale

I'm trying to write a piano score on Finale 2014 with sustain pedals such that there is not any gap between them. I have tried the *Custom Line Tool* from the *Smart Shape Tool*, adjusting each pedal's hooks as close as possible, without leaving any space uncovered. However, when playing, it sounds a gap without pedal at the ending of each pedal.

[image]

How could this task be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make 2 versions:

1. a print version (like your example)
2. and an audio where you keep the notes like you want (try with *edit note length* or accents e.g. *tenuto* in %)

Answer (score 0):

Notate the pedal under the first three notes as shown, then write *simile*.